# Is MVC a good choice for computational cluster?

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, mvvm

I have to implement a computational cluster for classes. Me and collagues I work with decided that we should introduce some architectural pattern to do our assignement right. We settled on Model-View-Controller since it's the most popular and we already have a bit of experience with MVVM which is similar.

Our last assignement was implementing a system for a fictional movie rental company that included database and GUI made in WPF. The distinction between Model, Model-View and View was easy. The database entities were Models, XAML was the View, etc.

Now, our computational cluster is a multi-module system where the user loads problem data (XML) via console and can later retrieve the solution. I cannot see what could possibly be, say, the Model in our application; the View (Console?) seems to do almost nothing. Is MVC even applicable for this kind of project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view (Console) is indeed very light weight.  But thinking about separating your view from your logic is always a good idea, even if it's just a main() method interface.

The model is almost definitely the jobs that you are executing, the "solution" that they retrieve later, and probably some model of the input (xml) that is being submitted, and probably some status-stuff that you create as you are executing the jobs.

The Controller is the code that is shuffling the xml from the console to the model for execution, and then starting the job.